# Creating Community User, You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested

Tags: community, customer-community, user, owd

I am having a system administrator profile. I have enabled the Community Site and Created the new Profile **CMS Portal** under **Customer Community User Licence**.

From the contact object i am `Enable Customer User` and assigning the `CMS Portal` Profile. On create of the User getting below error

```
**Insufficient Privileges**
You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary. 
For more information, see Insufficient Privileges Errors.
```

Please suggest me how to get this fixed. I check the object permission for this profile can edit / view all

Answer (score 0):

You would need to contact salesforce(or Account executive) who can enable "Lite portal users" and "High Volume Customer Portal users" license permission in your org.

Thanks